# Using jbuilder in rails to construct an array of objects with different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

A model(FirstModel) in my rails app has a has_many relationship with another model(Item).

```
class FirstModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy

  def item_array
    a = []
    self.items.each do |item|
      a.push(item.item_thing)
    end
    a
  end
end
```

Item itself belongs :item_thing through a polymorphic association.  A method on FirstModel returns an array of "items", not the join model object(which is of class Item), but the item_thing of each Item object, and therefore it is an array of objects of different classes (checked in rails console, and the method returns the array just fine)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_thing,  :polymorphic => true


end
```

In my show.json.jbuilder for FirstModel, I want to take that array of "items" and use different templates based on which class the item belongs to.  The following file path is "views/api/items/show.jbuilder"

```
json.extract! @item, :name

json.items @item.item_array do |item|
  if item.class == 'Book'
    json.partial! 'api/books/show', item
  end
  if item.class == 'Car'
    json.partial! 'api/cars/show', item
  end
end
```

The car and book template paths are "views/api/cars/show.json.jbuilder" and "views/api/books/show.json.jbuilder.

When I get the json from the above template the name of the FirstModel object is visible, items array is empty, whereas I am trying to get an array of hashes for each item, rendered through its respective template.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code will work if you change your class strings to actual class names.

I.e. `User` and not `"User"`.

Or you could keep the strings and use `.class.to_s`, which will return `"User"` for a user record.

If you're interested in metaprogramming, the `constantize`, `camelify` and `underscore` methods from activesupport might be useful down the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can probaly just do something like the code below if you name your items and partials correctly.

```
json.items @item.item_array do |item|
  json.partial! "api/#{item.class.to_s.pluralize.downcase}/show"
end
```

Alternatively you could use a case statement on `item.class.to_s`, or as one of the other answers suggested, use the class actual class instead of the class name as a string.